# Passing Correct POST request from React component, but Django view is receiving an empty dictionary

Tags: reactjs, django, post, axios, http-post

In my application, users can play songs and the play count is supposed to get updated in the backend. When I pass the song ID of the song that needs it's play count incremented, it is being passed as None. When I hardcode a song ID into the Django view, the plays are incremented like it's supposed to, but when I try to use the song ID that is passed from the frontend, it passes None.

This is the where the handlePlay function is called, which handles the play count update

```
<audio
   controls
   src={`/media/${song.file}`}
   data-song-id={song.id}
   onPlay={() => handlePlay(song.id)}
></audio>
```

This is the handlePlay function which makes the request to the backend. Both of the console.log(songID) lines are correctly logging the song ID in the browser console.

```
function handlePlay(songID) {
    console.log(songID)
    axios
      .post('/api/update-plays/', { "songID": songID })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log(songID)
  }
```

This is the updatePlays Django view which gets the song ID, finds the song, then increments the play count. When I print(request.POST), it prints an empty dictionary.

```
@csrf_exempt
def updatePlays(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        songID = request.POST.get("songID")
        song = Song.objects.get(id=songID)
        song.plays += 1
        song.save()
        return JsonResponse({"song": song}, safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({"error": "error"})
```

When I hardcode the actual song ID into the Django view, the song increment actually works fine. The problem is passing the song ID to the Django view, even though when I console log the song ID in the React component it is the correct value, I don't know why in the Django view it comes as an empty dictionary. Then when I search for the song with the id of the empty dictionary, of course it comes up as not found.